# Email from Logback with variable value read from App.propeties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, cloud-foundry

My Requirement is to send an EMails from Logback.xml file if any error occurs in my application and in EMail subject : I need to send a value coming from Application.properties file which is again being filled by External source.

in the below Code : 
If I keep spring.app.url and spring.app.name as constant ( uncommenting first 2 lines in application.properties file and commenting out last 2 ) : I am able to achieve my requirements but as soon as i try to get this values from env variables : it doesn't sent the value in emails ( though it print it correctly in my class )

LoggingTest Class File :

```
@RestController
public class LoggingTest {
Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(LoggingTest.class);


  @Value("${spring.app.url}")
  String environmentUrl;

  @Value("${spring.app.name}")
  String appName;

@RequestMapping("/")
public String Home() {
    System.out.println("Test environmentUrl : " + environmentUrl);
    System.out.println("Test appName : " + appName);
    logger.error("Error Occured : Send EMail");

    return "Hello";
}}
```

Application.properties file :

```
#spring.app.url="Dummy Application URL"
#spring.app.name="Dummy Application Name"
spring.app.url=${vcap.services.<ServiceName>.credentials.url}
spring.app.name=${vcap.application.name}
```

Logback.xml file :

```
<configuration>
<property resource="application.properties" />
<appender name="errMailer" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender">
  <smtpHost>host values</smtpHost>
  <smtpPort>port number</smtpPort>
  <from>abc@xyz.com</from>
  <to>abc@xyz.com</to>
  <subject>App-Name : ${spring.app.name}</subject>
  <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.html.HTMLLayout"/>
  <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
      <level>ERROR</level>
  </filter>
</appender>
<root level="ERROR">
    <appender-ref ref="errMailer" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I assume that the logbacks property resolver is not the same as springs resolver. Latter resolves also the variable reference in the value part, the logback resolver does not. I guess the subject of your sent mail is "App-Name : ${vcap.application.name}".

Comment: excatly right : instead of resolving the value of ${vcap.application.name} : it is treating it as a string and sending subject line as "App-Name : ${vcap.application.name}"

Answer (score 0):

The logback's property resolver is not the same as springs resolver. Latter resolves also a variable reference in the value part, the logback resolver does not.

Thus, you should re-configure the logback appender by code at startup after the spring environment has been loaded, e.g.:

```
@Component
public class MyBean 
{
    @Autowired
    private Configuration myEnv;

    @EventListener
    public void onAppStart(ContextRefreshedEvent event) 
    {
        // re-configure here your logback appender
        String value = myEnv.get("spring.app.name");
        appender.setSubject(value);
    }
}
```

An EventListener which has the formal parameter ContextRefreshedEvent is called after spring has been initialized.